# Bootstrap Modal preserves space on hiding

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap 3.

I have multiple modals in my page. I am hiding modal using below code:

```
$('.modal-1').modal('hide');
```

which hides the modal but some of modal's attributes are not updated. due to that i can't click anywhere in page.
For example: **aria-modal="true"** is not updated to **aria-hidden="true"** on hiding modal. and class **show** which is assigned to modal on open, not removed itself when modal is hidden.

I have found similar questions and tried to solve using below code:

```
$(".modal-backdrop").remove();
$('.modal-1').removeClass('show');
```

but it doesn't work.

Anybody has faced similar issue before? Please guide.

**Edit:**

**HTML**

```
 <div class="modal fade modal-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" id="closeModal" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                 /*** My content ***/
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show us your html and js code?

Comment: @Utkarsh I have added HTML part.  Related JS code i have already posted. I am calling $('.modal-1').modal('hide'); this line on button click which is inside modal

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give a id to your modal pop up and then try to hide it:

```
$("#Modal").attr("aria-hidden", "true");
$("#Modal").modal('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(document.body).removeClass("modal-open");
$(".modal-backdrop").remove();
$('.modal-1').modal('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need this

```
$('.modal-1').modal('hide');
```

data-dismiss should handle all of what you need

Comment: data-dismiss won't work for me as i have to hide it after i get response from my ajax call